# Forgetting something - Python BeautifulSoup and FinViz

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm getting stuck trying to grab the text values off the a.href tags. I've managed to isolate the the target values but keep running into an error when I try to get_text().

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = 'http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=152&s=ta_topgainers&o=price&c=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,25,63,64,65,66,67'
html = requests.get(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
main_div = soup.find('div', attrs = {'id':'screener-content'})
table = main_div.find('table')
sub = table.findAll('tr')
rows = sub[5].findAll('td')
for row in rows:
    data = row.a
    print data
```

Comment: I don't see any calls to `get_text` here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are actually trying to print `data.get_text()`, it would fail for some of the `row` in `rows` - because, in some cases, there are no child link elements in the `td` cells. You can check that a link was found beforehand:

```
for row in rows:
    link = row.a
    if link is not None:
        print(link.get_text())
```

Note that "row" and "rows" are probably not the best variable names since you are actually iterating over the "cells" - `td` elements.

Comment: right - a loop to iterate past the empty elements. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: What about iterating over the first "1" that populates?

Comment: @citra_amarillo the first "1" - could you please elaborate more about what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: sure - so the returns from print(link.get_text()) are formatted similarly to the rows in the table from the site. Yet, there is a leading "1" preceding the actual id 1. When I try to iterate past it using something like [1:]: I get errored out. New question - what would be the clean way to prep the text for storage in an obj. db. I've been trying to format it  like data{
'id' : link[0].get_text(), 'ticker' : link[1].get_text() } etc...
and have been getting stuck there too - I can ask another quation too if that would be better.

Comment: @citra_amarillo thanks for the story - yes, please create a separate question - more people can potentially help and it's overall more convenient.